# Uniqueness of $p^{th}$ powers in characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The other day, my undergrad Galois theory professor used the fact that in char $p$, $p$th powers exist and are unique. How can one understand why uniqueness holds?

Thanks

Comment: Of course $p$th powers exist and are unique in any ring: this just means that $x^p$ is uniquely defined.  So this is probably not what you meant to ask.  By the way, if you overheard your instructor say something that doesn't quite sound right to you: ask the instructor.  Maybe you're confused or you misheard her; maybe she didn't say exactly what she wanted to say.  (Or just maybe she was actually mistaken.  Math professors are professionals, but still human beings: we can and do make mistakes.)  But she is the best equipped person to clear up the confusion: that's what she's there for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x^p = y^p$, then $(x-y)^p = x^p-y^p=0$, since $p$ divides the binomial coefficient ${p\choose k}$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$.

Note that this is not really the uniqueness of p-th *powers*, but rather p-th roots, which certainly do not always exist.  They do exist over a finite field, because $x\mapsto x^p$ is injective, hence surjective.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure about your comment about "not really." It does seem like it means that $p$th powers are unique - saying $p$th powers are unique to me means that $x\to x^p$ is $1-1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It was clear enough that I understood the question, but it just doesn't sound quite right to my ear.  I'm not very attached to my criticism, though.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion between p-th powers and p-th power roots floating around...